# IndexError: list index out of range - python recursive diff of folders - 2.7

Tags: python, json, recursion, indexing, path

I am trying to perform a recursive diff of json output of a test run stored in multiple nested folders against a reference folder with 2 nested folders.  The output should be a csv file that shows The name of the compared files and only the lines that are different and what value is different in each file.

A developer gave me this code two years ago and when it worked perfectly; however, try to change the location of the reference `folderBaseReference` folder I get `binDetail1 = row1[2]  IndexError: list index out of range`

If I add another parent folder I get empty diff results, can someone help me correct this script?

```
import os
from os import path
import glob
import json
import time


buildNumber = ""
folderBaseReference = "C:\\PostDH3\\"
folderBaseCompare = "C:\\date\\22v19\\"
resultFile = "ED23_ALL_testResults_" +time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S") + ".csv"
testRuns = ['_DateData_WidthBin','_DateData_NumBin','_NumData_WidthBin','_NumData_NumBin']
#testRuns = ['']


def findAndLoadFile(testCaseFolder,filename):
    files =  glob.glob(path.join(testCaseFolder,filename))
    if len(files) != 1:
        raise Exception('error finding file')
    filepath = path.join(testCaseFolder,files[0])

    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    return (data,filepath)


def compareFunc(data1obj,data2obj):
    errors = []    
    for i,v in enumerate(data1obj["data"]):
        row1 = v
        row2 = data2obj["data"][i]
        dataCheck = row1[0] == row2[0] 
        if not dataCheck:
            errors.append( {'same':False,'error': 'data index = ' + str(i) + " , " + str(row1[0]) + " , " + str(row2[0])})

        binDetail1 = row1[2]  #########   Line 46  #########
        binDetail1["binNumber"] = row1[1]

        binDetail2 = row2[1]
        for subProp in ["algorithm","startval","startop","endval","endop","binNumber"]:    
            check = binDetail1[subProp] == binDetail2[subProp]
            if not check:
                errors.append( {'same':False,'error': 'data index = ' + str(i) + "," + subProp + "," + str(binDetail1[subProp]) + "," + str(binDetail2[subProp])})
            #print subProp,binDetail1[subProp],binDetail2[subProp],check
    return errors





text_file = open(resultFile, "w")
for testRun in testRuns:
    dbFolders =  glob.glob(path.join(folderBaseCompare,'*'+testRun+"*")) 
    refernceFolder =  glob.glob(path.join(folderBaseReference,'*'+testRun+"*")) 
    print refernceFolder
    if len(refernceFolder) == 0:
        continue

    folderReference = path.join(folderBaseReference,refernceFolder[0])
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(folderReference) if path.isdir(path.join(folderReference,f))]
    for dbFolder in dbFolders:
        folderCompare = path.join(folderBaseCompare,dbFolder)
        print dbFolder

        text_file.write(dbFolder)
        text_file.write('\n')
        for folderName in files:
            print folderName

            testCaseFolder = path.join(folderReference,folderName)
            try:
                dvmBase,j = findAndLoadFile(testCaseFolder,'*dvm.txt')
            except Exception as e:
                print 'error finding dvm for reference test case'
                continue
            testCaseFolder = path.join(folderCompare,folderName)
            try:
                dvmCompare,j = findAndLoadFile(testCaseFolder,'*dvm.txt')
            except Exception as e:
                print 'error finding dvm for compare test case'
                continue
            dataobj1 = json.loads(dvmBase)
            dataobj2 = json.loads(dvmCompare)

            if "data" in dataobj1 and "data" in dataobj2:
###### Line 96 ############
                status =  json.dumps(compareFunc(dataobj1,dataobj2),indent=2)
                print ' ', status
                if len(status) > 2:
                    text_file.write(folderName)
                    text_file.write('\n') 
                    text_file.write(status)
                    text_file.write('\n') 
            else:
                print ' ', "nope"
                text_file.write("no data in dvm")
                text_file.write('\n') 

text_file.close()
```

Full Error:

```
runfile('H:/testdata/dh3_modificationnumericcomparegoldstandardtonew.py', wdir='H:/testdata')
['C:\\PostDH3\\SQLServer_NumData_WidthBin']
C:\date\22v19\Infobright_NumData_WidthBin
BinUniform_both_outlier_int_width10_unit_oFalse_pTrue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 790, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 77, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "H:/testdata/dh3_modificationnumericcomparegoldstandardtonew.py", line 96, in <module>
    status =  json.dumps(compareFunc(dataobj1,dataobj2),indent=2)
  File "H:/testdata/dh3_modificationnumericcomparegoldstandardtonew.py", line 46, in compareFunc
    binDetail1 = row1[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected Output from Comparing SQLServer_Standard_Results to Supported_DB's results file:

```
    C:\date\22v19\Postgres9_3_DateData_NumBin  #### Diff Found no changes from Reference Folder to Result Folder
C:\date\22v19\Infobright_DateData_NumBin  ### Diff found the following changes in the file C:\date\22v19\Infobright_DateData_NumBin\BinUniform_Twenty_years_num14_oFalse_pTrue\BinUniform_Twenty_years_num14_oFalse_pTrue_dvm.txt
BinUniform_Twenty_years_num14_oFalse_pTrue
[
  {
    "same": false, 
    "error": "data index = 91 , 1989-10-29T02:07:22 , 1989-10-29T01:07:22"
  }
]
BinUniform_Twenty_years_num30_oFalse_pTrue
[
  {
    "same": false, 
    "error": "data index = 91 , 1989-10-29T02:07:22 , 1989-10-29T01:07:22"
  }
]
BinUniform_Twenty_years_num30_oTrue_pTrue
[
  {
    "same": false, 
    "error": "data index = 91 , 1989-10-29T02:07:22 , 1989-10-29T01:07:22"
  }
]
C:\date\22v19\SQLServer_DateData_NumBin  ### No Changes
C:\date\22v19\Vertica_DateData_NumBin   ### No Changes
```

Comment: I'm trying to go through this and it's just a rabbit hole of tracing variable names backwards through the process. Also, your line numbers in the traceback don't match the lines in your first block of code. Please reduce this down. In any case, the stuff you've posted at the bottom is a series of lists with a single element in which only index `0` would be valid. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @roganjosh  I tried to update the issue so that it was a little clearer.  Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Your update changed only file paths (which we cannot test with anyway). My comment was that there is so much info in your question that it's boiling down to us doing general debugging. Please see the link in my initial comment; it's no easier to answer now than it was before.